# Cannot delete CakePHP3 Tree

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a model "Customers" with TreeBehavior which is working fine:

e.g.:

```
id  | parent_id | type    | name
----|-----------|---------|--------------
1   | NULL      | husband | Jon Doe 
2   | 1         | wife    | Jane Doe 
3   | 1         | child   | Jim Doe
```

A customer can have many "Contracts". All associations working perfectly.

Now, I try to delete the customer. This workes only for child elements (wife,child): If wife is deleted, all associated contracts will be also deleted. But if I try to delete the husband (parent_id = NULL), I get error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot
>   delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`contracts`, CONSTRAINT `contracts_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
>   REFERENCES `customers` (`id`))

SQL Query:

```
DELETE FROM customers WHERE ((lft) >= :c0 AND (lft) <= :c1)
```

I think there is a simple trick, what I have to do, but I do not find the solution. Maybe one of you guys can help?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update1**

If none of the child customers have contracts, then it seems that it is working.

Comment: I've configured my customer model:

$this->hasMany('Contracts', [
            'dependent' => true,
            'cascadeCallbacks' => true]);

So I can delete a customers also with his contracts. But this does not work for the contracts assigned to an assoicated child element.

Comment: Please mention your program to delete..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to let the ORM handle this automatically, as the tree behavior uses `Table::deleteAll()` to remove nodes in the subtree, which will create a `DELETE` query similar to what you're showing, ie the records are being delete at once, *not* one by one, which would be required for dependent/cascading deletes.

You may want to suggest an enhancement, I guess it would be nice if this would work, not sure though how complicated it might be.

A possible workaround on your end, might be to retrieve the children of the parent node, and manually delete them one by one from the outer most, up to the inner most. This may not perform very well though, as the tree would get synced on every delete, which in turn requires to reload entities before deleting them, as the `lft` and `rgt` values that they hold would otherwise be outdated.

Here's an untested example to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
$result = $this->Customers->connection()->transactional(function () {
    // retrieve the parent to delete
    $customer = $this->Customers->get(1);

    // retrieve the parents children
    $descendants = $this->Customers->find('children', ['for' => $customer->id]);

    // Reverse the childrens order, by default they are ordered
    // from the inner most to the outer most. This could probably
    // also be done on query level by sorting on the `lft` field.
    $entities = array_reverse($descendants->toArray());

    // append the parent so that it is being deleted last
    $entities[] = $customer;

    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
        $entity = $this->Customers->get($entity->id);
        if (!$this->Customers->delete($entity, ['atomic' => false])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
```

Theoretically this should delete the nodes one by one, causing their dependend contracts to be removed first.

Alternatively you could collect the tree nodes and their associated contracts, manually delete the contracts first, and then delete the parent tree node. That would probably perform better. Something along the lines of this:

```
$result = $this->Customers->connection()->transactional(function () {
    // retrieve the parent to delete
    $customer = $this->Customers->get(1, [
        'contain' => ['Contracts']
    ]);

    // retrieve the parents children
    $descendants = $this->Customers
        ->find('children', ['for' => $customer->id])
        ->contain(['Contracts']);

    // collect all contracts
    $contracts = $customer->contracts;
    foreach ($descendants as $entity) {
        $contracts = array_merge($contracts, $entity->contracts);
    }

    // delete contracts first
    // in case no callbacks are required for deleting contracts, 
    // you could also collect the customer or contract ids instead
    // and use `deleteAll()`
    foreach ($contracts as $entity) {
        if (!$this->Customers->Contracts->delete($entity, ['atomic' => false])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // then delete the customers
    if (!$this->Customers->delete($customer, ['atomic' => false])) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > Tree > Deleting Nodes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html#deleting-nodes)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Deleting Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Using Transactions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#using-transactions)**